# Are Eclipse memory boundaries necessary and why do they exist?

Tags: eclipse, memory, jvm-arguments

The `eclipse.ini` file by default defines memory boundaries for Eclipse with the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` parameters.

Why is that so? Is it safe to remove it if I have 8GB memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe those are the limits of how much RAM your eclipse can take up (including all your plugins, and programs running from eclipse). I suggest to keep those limits as they are not harming you, or increase them if that is not enough. Those limits prevent your programs that you are testing from eclipse, from taking up your entire RAM. And it might not be safe to remove them.

Comment: Well it's obvious that they're limits on how much RAM Eclipse takes - but I'm not sure that it applies to user's applications. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F and http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini I believe

Comment: Yes, it does apply to applications launched from eclipse, as they are in eclipse's runtime.